# Adding cookies to a request

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to make 2 requests to a remote server using apache httpcomponents
First request does a login and returns set of cookies which i am able to extract using

```
response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")
```

which gives me a list of [Lorg.apache.http.Header;
something like

```
Set-Cookie: cea-ssa=false; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: usersessionid=AggAAACkKmlfAAAAAAoAAAApuME9L24ldjttFAAAAMODfhQQoIqLb1yL/3UUU/Aa8yaiBwAAAFNIQS0yNTYgAAAATR7uNj5Ph5vsJ4dto8ke207d/636Xf4VwH/Pubq15+w=; Path=/; Secure
```

Now I have to use this list of Cookies and add it to the subsequent http request and I am confused in how to form the next HTTP Post request

I am using  `'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'` as the Client Library